# Using Dropbox API Drop-ins

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm using Dropbox APIs Drop-ins, when I try to save a file I get an error message like *Received non-200 response status 503 from server for url: http://www.example.com/test.txt*

In my html page I use the Dropbox.save(optionsUploader); function on an input button and my js script is:

```
optionsUploader = {

files: [

{'url':'http://www.example.com/test.txt', 'filename':'test.txt'}

],

success: function() {},

progress: function(progress) {console.log(progress);},

cancel: function() {},

error: function(errmsg) {console.log(errmsg);}

}
```

Is that because I'm working on localhost ? (the www.example.com address corresponds to a 127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox Saver works by having the Dropbox servers download the file at the supplied URL. In this case, it sounds like the supplied URL is actually a localhost (127.0.0.1) URL, which won't be accessible to the Dropbox servers. (That is, you may be serving the file on your local computer, but this isn't openly available on Internet.)

The error message is telling you this, in that it's saying that the servers tried to access the file at the supplied URL but got the HTTP error code 503 ("Service Unavailable").

So, this being the case, to use the Saver, you'll need to supply a URL that's actually accessible on the Internet. This may mean hosting files on your server, or some CDN, or even a Dropbox link.